# Why do encryped RSA bytes in Java variate?

Tags: java, arrays, encryption, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I try to code a hybrid encryption to communicate between server and client. So I send a public RSA key from the client the server enrypts his AES key and sends it back. But then if i decrypt it on client site, the key is longer than i send it and i don't know why...

Here the code:

Client:

```
socket.getOutputStream().write(security.getKeyPair().getPublic().getEncoded());
byte[] keyBuffer = new byte[512];
socket.getInputStream().read(keyBuffer);
security.setKey(new SecretKeySpec(security.decryptRSA(keyBuffer).getBytes(), "AES"));
```

Server:

```
byte[] keyBuffer = new byte[550];
this.socket.getInputStream().read(keyBuffer);
PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBuffer));
this.socket.getOutputStream().write(this.security.encryptRSA(this.security.getKey().getEncoded(), publicKey));
```

Security class methods:

```
public byte[] encryptRSA(byte[] message, PublicKey key) {
        byte[] buffer = message;
        try {
            this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            this.cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            buffer = this.cipher.doFinal(buffer);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return buffer;
    }


public String decryptRSA(byte[] message) {
        byte[] buffer = message;
        try {
            this.cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            this.cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.keyPair.getPrivate());
            buffer = this.cipher.doFinal(buffer);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new String(buffer);
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: A properly generated AES key should be arbitrary binary data not characters -- one from Java `KeyGenerator` _definitely_ is -- and Java `String` is not designed to and frequently does not preserve binary data. Treat an AES key as `byte[]` everywhere not as a `String`.

Comment: What exception do you get?  Is your app waiting to receive / send some data?  You seems to send/receive data with assuming lengths. And as already answered, if your key contains non-printable characters, `new String(buffer)` definitely may scrap these

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely that you stringified your code needlessly:

```
   return new String(buffer);
```

This will interpret the buffer in a certain way as a string. However, the key consists of random bytes, which may decode to unexpected characters. Then you revert back to bytes using `.getBytes()`, but by then it is too late.

From the Java `String(byte[]): String` constructor documentation:

> The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the default charset is unspecified. The `CharsetDecoder` class should be used when more control over the decoding process is required.

Usually though it simply silently drops bytes that cannot be decoded, although representing the unknown encoding with a Unicode character or question mark may also happen. In any of these operations information is lost.

Simply leave the AES key to be bytes and that part should be fixed.

---

Besides that, `read` is not the same as `readNBytes​` (and just `read` is wrong), but that's probably not the error; you'd get into trouble with RSA, not the AES key if it would be the problem.

---

Note that you can retrieve the modulus size in bytes to determine the amount of bytes to read, so you don't need to have a 512 constant there either (which I would write as `KEY_SIZE / Byte.SIZE` where `KEY_SIZE = 4096` to at least indicate that the buffer is the same as the key size clearly.

Comment: Hi Maarten, thanks for your comment about my answer. You are right, I was totally wrong.

Comment: No problem :) Glad you reacted to it the way you did.